# Can't update to 20.04 from 19.10

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates, 20.04, 19.10

So im rather new this whole linux stuff but i took a pc and installed 18.04 on it. after using that for a while i decided that i wanted a change in scenery so i upgraded to 19.10 since that was the version it told me was the latest... this all went fine, no complications at all. later on i was on my normal pc that runs windows and i made an ubuntu vm out of sheer boredom and saw that 20.04 was actually the latest release when i was looking for an iso as the one i had was still 18.04. so when i went back on to 19.10 machine i thought i would be as simple it was upgrading from 18.04, but boy was i wrong. the only error ive really gotten is "This version no longer supported. Please install a supported version." anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 is actually easier than from 18.04->19.10, however 19.10 is now EOL.  On upgrades, I'd always suggest you first check out the release notes of the release you want to go to, ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes (which mentions upgrades from 18.04 or 19.10).  Your upgrade is more complex as you missed the windows, 19.10 now being EOL - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  (ensure you system is fully upgraded first, then I'd expect *release-upgrade* to still work, but it'll depend on your mirror & other complications due to now EOL)

Comment: My prior comment about mirrors (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) is because mirrors can drop a release **after** its reached EOL, which can mean the following day, or months after...  Thus sources may need changing, to ensure you have been fully upgraded; and it'll then allow *release-upgrade* as outlined in release notes. If you have problems, provide command & messages in your question for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ubuntu 19.10 is an edition with short time support. It is now end of life for just a little time, so indeed remaining installs cannot anymore be updated. Your only option now is to perform a fresh install.

A fresh install is in general the best approach. You then start afresh with a new system configured according to the latest insights. No old configuration data is lingering around.

Comment: yeah thats about what i ended up doing, its okay tho i didnt lose much of anything, just my time and sanity lol thanks for the help tho.